# Use default values in method from association or XYZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my code, Author has_many Books, so I could do something like:

```
@author.books
```

If the author has no books, when `@author.books` is called, I'd like a default book object with that author's info already filled out (i.e. author_id), something like:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  def books
    the_books || default_book
  end
end
```

That's obviously not real code, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This might not be a good idea, since .books return an ActiveRecord Association object (Many books) and what you want to do will return a Book object.

Comment: And what is the reason doing this?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - how do I return the default value if it exists - otherwise return XYZ?

Comment: Something like this? `def author_books self.books.empty? ? Book.new(author_id: self.id) : self.books end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  alias :__books__ :books

  def books
    result = __books__
    result.empty? ? default_books : result
  end

  private
  def default_books
    # ...
  end
end
```